# Airflow execution_timeout settings not respected

Tags: airflow

In my tasks, I have `execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=1)` set in my task and `'dagrun_timeout': timedelta(minutes=2)` for my DAG, and this is correctly reflected in the web GUI's Task Instance Details. However, none of my task instances are actually set to failed or retry when breaching the one minute threshold. Rather, they time out at 11 minutes...

> [2017-11-02 18:00:05,376] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2017-11-02 18:00:05,370] {base_hook.py:67} INFO - Using connection to: [REDACTED]
>
> [2017-11-02 18:10:06,505] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2017-11-02 18:10:06,504] {timeout.py:37} ERROR - Process timed out

Do I have a problem with my configuration, or is there something buggy happening with how Airflow interprets time out settings?

Comment: Might be better to help if you have the code sample of your task operator and dag, also what task you are trying to run? it is not clear in none of my task instances are actually set to failed

Comment: Any resolution to your problem?